# Why doesn't the background color animate in Internet Explorer using d3?

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, d3.js

I'm trying to animate the background color of an element with D3.  This works correctly in other browsers but not IE9, there the elements stay the initial color.  I don't see why it should fail, so can anyone point out my mistake?

```js
d3.selectAll('.block').data(['foo', 'bar'])
                             .enter()
                             .append('div')
                             .classed('block', true)
.text(String)
.style('background-color', '#3B88CF')
          .transition()
          .delay(1500)
          .duration(1500)
          .style('background-color', '#1e2a42')
```

```css
.block{
    display: inline-block;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 4px 8px;
    margin: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```